# How do you redirect after using the javascript sdk, facebook login on my site

Tags: c#, facebook, redirect, authentication

I'm using the javascript call to do a facebook login on my site but after redirecting I cannot access the 'Access Token code' ("&code=" + code) from the querystring.  It’s used to get the user information from the url starting 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?..."&code=" + code' if I don't use the redirect it doesn't seem to hit the code behind on the master page either to get the user info. 
Should I be doing this another way.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
FB.init({
    appId: '123456789123456',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    //oauth: true,
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
      window.location = "http://localhost/facebook/facebookauth.aspx";
  });
};
(function (d) {
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));
```

Thanks in advance

kitemark

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a library like [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net).  The NerdDinner project provides an example usage of a javascript control for logging in using one of these providers.  The code can be downloaded from its Codeplex home page http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/